# Return 4 slightly different copies of each record

Tags: oracle, concatenation, repeat

I have a large, somewhat unwieldy Oracle query that generates thousands of records. I now have to add a new field that generates a code value for each record. The code value has the format:

```
<A|B><1|2><city>
```

Here, `<city>` is a field returned by the query. The final data set needs to have 4 copies of each record: for example, if the city is Boston, then the code values are:

```
A1Boston
A2Boston
B1Boston
B2Boston
```

Everything else in these 4 records needs to be identical, and I have to generate these 4 records for each record in the original query.

Is there a programmatic way to do this other than (1) making a temp table with the code value combinations, then joining on it, or (2) selecting into a variable and iterating over it? I actually have to do this same thing for several other equally large queries, so I'd like to do something repeatable, if that is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the code dynamic or fixed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need, this could be a way to solve:

```
with test(something, city) as
(
    select 1, 'Boston' from dual union all
    select 1, 'Boston' from dual union all
    select 1, 'Boston' from dual union all
    select 1, 'Boston' from dual union all
    select 1, 'Boston' from dual union all
    select 6, 'N.Y.'   from dual union all
    select 6, 'N.Y.'   from dual union all
    select 6, 'N.Y.'   from dual union all
    select 7, 'L.A.'   from dual union all
    select 7, 'L.A.'   from dual
) 
select case when RN in (1, 2) then 'A' else 'B' end 
       ||
       case when RN in (1, 3) then '1' else '2' end,
       city,
       something
from (
        select city, something, row_number() over (partition by city order by null) as RN
        from test
     )
where RN <= 4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a sub query to generate a prefix values, and than join it with your query

```
select 
  prefix || city, field1, field2 ...
from
  ( select city,  field1, field2 ... /* your query */ )
cross join
  ( select 'A1' as prefix from dual
    UNION ALL
     select 'A2' as prefix from dual
    UNION ALL
     select 'B1' as prefix from dual
    UNION ALL
     select 'B2' as prefix from dual
  )
```

select

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code value is static, maybe this will give you an idea of how to do it:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'Boston' city FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 'New York' city FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, 'Detroit' city FROM dual)
SELECT dummy1.col1||dummy2.col1||sd.city results
FROM   sample_data sd
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'A' col1 FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 'B' col1 FROM dual) dummy1
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL col1
                   FROM   dual
                   CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2) dummy2
ORDER BY sd.city, dummy1.col1, dummy2.col1;

RESULTS
-------------------------------------------------
A1Boston
A2Boston
B1Boston
B2Boston
A1Detroit
A2Detroit
B1Detroit
B2Detroit
A1New York
A2New York
B1New York
B2New York
```

By having the two cross joins, you make it easier to amend the query should you the code value change, e.g. <A|B|C><1|2|3|4><city> - if you were hardcoding the rows to cross join to (i.e. 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', etc), you would have to write out all 12 combinations, instead of just working with the 7 specified values in the code value.

Comment: This solution gets my vote too - Cartesian (or "cross") join is the best solution in this type of problems.

Comment: @Boneist Perfect, this is exactly what I need (and it's elegant as well). I tried it yesterday, and it worked great. Thanks for your help!